# DISCORD BOT How to search and replace a url and getting the discord input

Tags: python, discord

How do I make my discord bot take any input on a player that says +search debuunked

and when I said that It will add debuunked in the last URL here:

https://www.facebook.com/ I want debuunked to be added after the slash, Kindly Help me Thanks :)
USING DISCORD.PY

```
if message.content == '+search' + "%s" + str(message):
    await message.channel.send(f"https://www.facebook.com/{message}")
```

This is my code ^^

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is no way for us to reproduce your problem...

Comment: Sorry for that, I sent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** You can use the following code if you want to check if the message starts with '+search '

What this code does is using the startswith function. This function identifies when a string initial characters match the ones you introduce as parameters.

Then, once it is checked positively, using message.content.replace('+search ','') what you do is to substitute the string for an empty space, that way you only keep everything that is in message.content except for the initial string.

```py
if message.content.startswith('+search '):
    await message.channel.send(f"https://www.facebook.com/{message.content.replace('+search ','')}")
```

Comment: I actually want the players input after the +search and space to be stored in a variable but I don't know how to :(

Comment: like when I say +search debuunked
I want debuunked to be stored in a variable and put the variable after the slash
https://www.facebook.com/ I want it to be put here

Comment: Hello it seems to work now, Thank you but can you please explain what did you do for this to work before I make it as a solved? Thank you :))